# Multiple keys with same values in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Basically what I'm looking to do is have 2+ different keys pointing to the same value.

Something like:

```
"AP7898",
"AP7841"    => array('loadStatusLoad' => '.1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.12.2.3.1.1.2',
                     'loadStatusStatus => '.1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.12.2.3.1.1.3',                                      
               ),
```

both are ap7898 and ap7841 point to the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$val = 'hi';
$arr = array(
  'a1' => $val,
  'a2' => $val
);
```

or use references

```
$val = 'hi';
$arr = array(
  'a1' => &$val,
  'a2' => &$val
);


$val = 'bye'; // both are updated
```

Comment: The only issue is the array is defined in a class. the above won't work. Sorry. Didn't realize that would be an issue.

Comment: it'll work fine. obviously copy paste wont work. references can be confusing.

Comment: i'll mark this as the answer. i think i have a syntax error which is cause issues. thanks.

Comment: quick follow up as to why the code wasn't working. my error was because i was trying to do actual "code" outside of a function in a class. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Why not setup the parent array, setup the first key/value pair, and copy to the second?

```
$status = array( 'AP7898', 'AP7841' );

$status['AP7898'] = array('loadStatusLoad' => '.1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.12.2.3.1.1.2',
                     'loadStatusStatus' => '.1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.12.2.3.1.1.3');

$status['AP7841'] = $status['AP7898'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have possibility to modify them using either of keys, you are looking for [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).